# Copy only the input folder files whose names match value from JSON or CSV file

Tags: bash

### Input:

- a folder containing LOTS of files (with a complex file hierarchy)
- a JSON/CSV file containing filenames

### Output:

- a new folder containing files copied from input folder and matching filenames in CSV/JSON file

I kind of have a limited knowledge of batch/sed/awk, so any idea/suggestion is welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show an example of the JSON file's contents please?

Comment: Suggestions or should we write your code for you? http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: bash/sed/awk is probably the wrong choice for JSON parsing

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments above, bash/sed/awk is the not ideal for parsing JSON. Since you've hinted that CSV is an option, I'd say that's your best bet.

Since I don't know if this is an assignment and you've yet to mention what you've attempted, I'll refrain from writing a full script for you. Instead, here's a quick run-through of the core bits which will hopefully help you forward.

And since you've did not provide an example input file, I'm going to make one up. Say you have an input CSV file as such:

```
$ cat in.csv
john,hello/world/domination.txt,10
ruth,some_file.txt,20
sarah,jessica/parker.jpg,80
```

#### Looping through contents of the CSV file

The simplest way would be to use a `while` loop and [`read`](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html):

```
$ while IFS=',' read -r NAME FILENAME AGE; do echo "$FILENAME"; done < in.csv
hello/world/domination.txt
some_file.txt
jessica/parker.jpg
in/my documents/empty.file
```

Note that we've temporarily changed `IFS` (internal file separator) to a comma to split the input CSV lines into fields.

#### The copy command

Assuming that in your script you have a base path (your *"... folder containing LOTS of files (with a complex file hierarchy)"*) and a destination directory as such:

```
BASE_PATH="/some/source/"
DEST_PATH="/the/destination/"
```

and for each filename from the CSV file -- say `hello/world/domination.txt` -- you want to end up copying from `/some/source/hello/world/domination.txt` to `/the/destination/hello/world/domination.txt`, then there are 3 steps involved:

1. Create the `FROM` and `TO` paths by appending the strings:

   ```
   FROM="${BASE_PATH}/${FILENAME}"
   TO="${DEST_PATH}/${FILENAME}"
   ```
2. Make sure that the destination directory exist. We use `dirname` to extract the name of the directory, and `mkdir -p` to recursively create directories if they do not yet exist:

   ```
   mkdir -p "$(dirname $TO)"
   ```
3. Perform the actual copy

   ```
   cp "$FROM" "$TO"
   ```

The quotes around the arguments for `mkdir` and `cp` ensure that paths with spaces are not treated as separate arguments.

Note that for brevity, I've left out error checking. In a production script you'd generally want to include checks to ensure that the source files exist and is readable, and the destination path is writeable.

#### putting it all together

Assuming you have already assigned `BASE_PATH` and `DEST_PATH`:

```
while IFS=',' read -r NAME FILENAME AGE
do
    FROM="${BASE_PATH}/${FILENAME}"
    TO="${DEST_PATH}/${FILENAME}"
    mkdir "$(dirname $TO)"
    cp "$FROM" "$TO"
done < in.csv
```

Comment: cut is not needed. `while IFS=',' read -r val1 val2 val3; do ...; done < in.csv`

Comment: Thanks jordanm. That's absolutely right. However, the OP has stated that he/she is new to scripting and this is my attempt at a step-by-step approach with the hope that each piece is potentially transferrable to future tasks. In this instance, it shows how the output of arbitrary commands can be iterated.

Comment: @jordanm after some thought, I've come to agree with you that the 'proper' way is likely to be more readable. Answer updated. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give a whole lot for us to go on, so I will assume that

- you use a CSV file
- located in the root of the source directory
- is formatted as `file1,file2,...`
- that `file1` is *just* a filename, not the full path to that file.

In that case (which is the simplest case), you can try something like

```
#!/bin/bash

# some renaming for easier read
srccsv="$(basename "$1")"
srcdir="$(dirname "$1")"
trgtdir="$2"

# perform the copy
set +o posix
cp <(IFS=,; \
    while read filename; do \
        find "$srcdir" -type f -name "$filename" -print0; \
    done < "$srccsv") "$trgtdir"
```

Then run it via

```
./cp_csv.sh path/to/your/csv path/to/your/targetdir
```

Supposing you've named this script `cp_csv.sh`.

Note: It's bash-specific (because of process substitution), and I didn't test this (it's very late over here..), but I don't see why this would fail.

If you're using a JSON input file, that'll be much more of a pain to parse in bash. As indicated by @jordanm, bash/sed/awk isn't the right tool for that.